# "Summarise" query with dplyr vs plyr

Tags: r, dplyr, plyr

this is my first question so I apologise if I haven't got the questioning protocol correct.

I'm comparing dplyr and plyr in R to summarise data from a data frame.

The data frame is simple. I have a drug, a set of patients and within each patient a set of responses consisting of a sample and a numerical value, or level of the drug in this sample.

The operation I am performing I am summing up the `level`, i.e. the response of the patient to the drug, over each `sample` for each combination of `patient` and `drug`.

The summarise operations in both libraries are giving different answers. Plyr looks correct. The sum in the third row of metric should not be NA as there are no `NA`s in this subset. Plyr matches what I calculate by hand for this group.

Any idea what is going on? I expect it is something to do with the way dplyr is handling `NAs` in the first patient "AB" in the summarise step.

**Reproducable example**

```
library(plyr)
library(dplyr)

panel <- structure(list(drug = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
                                  1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = "Paracetamol", class = "factor"), 
               patient = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
                                     2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L), .Label = c("AB", "AC", "AD"), class = "factor"), 
               sample = structure(c(6L, 8L, 12L, 9L, 5L, 3L, 9L, 1L, 
                                         2L, 11L, 7L, 10L, 2L, 13L, 4L), 
                                       .Label = c("AH", "AT", "BV", 
                                        "CD", "CK", "CM", "CU", "CV", "CZ", "DK", "DM", "DN", "DO"
                                         ), class = "factor"), 
               level = c(NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, 
                         0.00153937362708914, 0.000136048826793052, 0.0589067431555789, 
                         0.00798507232520125, 0.000179913435935396, 0.00338149695926075, 
                         0.000365122058519732, 0.0138121831347925, 0.000309530166151126, 
                         0.00518926294072875)), .Names = c("drug", "patient", "sample_type", 
                         "level"), row.names = c(NA, -15L), class = "data.frame")

plyr_version <- ddply(panel,
                      .(drug, patient),
                      mutate,
                      sum_level = sum(level)) %>%
  ddply(.(drug, patient), summarise, metric = sum(sum_level))

dplyr_version <- group_by(panel, drug, patient) %>%
  mutate(sum_level = sum(level)) %>% 
  summarise(metric = sum(sum_level))

print("Plyr\n")
print.data.frame(plyr_version)

print("Dplyr")
print.data.frame(dplyr_version)
```

**Obtained Result**

```
[1] "Plyr\n"
         drug patient    metric
1 Paracetamol      AB       NaN
2 Paracetamol      AC 0.3437358
3 Paracetamol      AD 0.1152880
[1] "Dplyr"
         drug patient    metric
1 Paracetamol      AB        NA
2 Paracetamol      AC 0.3437358
3 Paracetamol      AD        NA
```

If I use `na.rm = TRUE` in the sum_level step then the results match, 
ie `sum_level = sum(level, na.rm = TRUE))`, giving:

```
[1] "Plyr"
         drug patient    metric
1 Paracetamol      AB 0.0000000
2 Paracetamol      AC 0.3437358
3 Paracetamol      AD 0.1152880
[1] "Dplyr"
         drug patient    metric
1 Paracetamol      AB 0.0000000
2 Paracetamol      AC 0.3437358
3 Paracetamol      AD 0.1152880
```

**edited -  added sessionInfo**

```
R version 3.3.0 (2016-05-03)
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0 (64-bit)
Running under: OS X 10.11.5 (El Capitan)

locale:
[1] en_GB.UTF-8/en_GB.UTF-8/en_GB.UTF-8/C/en_GB.UTF-8/en_GB.UTF-8

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] dplyr_0.4.3 plyr_1.8.4 

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] Rcpp_0.12.5      lattice_0.20-33  assertthat_0.1   grid_3.3.0       R6_2.1.2         nlme_3.1-128     gtable_0.2.0     DBI_0.4-1        magrittr_1.5     scales_0.4.0    
[11] ggplot2_2.1.0    lazyeval_0.2.0   tools_3.3.0      munsell_0.4.3    parallel_3.3.0   colorspace_1.2-6
```

Comment: Hi, I thought I'd run the code you've provided and I'm unable to replicate your error. Also, depending on the way you've loaded your libraries one will mask the other's `summarise` function.

Comment: @Arun I can replicate the error, but not sure why. miepstei, could you print a session info?

Comment: @drmariod have now added - sorry should have added initially.  I know that using plyr and dplyr means that functions get masked. It doesn't make a difference in this case as I have run it without the plyr library and plyr commands and get the same result with dplyr.

Comment: I believe the issue with NA values and odd results has been fixed.  Try updating to dplyr 0.5.0.

Comment: @aosmith doh! quite correct. Please can you reply instead of comment so I can tick your answer?